# Is there a WS-* Standard for specifying and propagate a correlation ID in the SOAP header?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I am looking for a WS-* standard for propagating a correlation ID (in the form of a UUID) in the SOAP Header.  My scenario has to do with SOAP/JMS and I want to put a correlation ID that is preserved as a message moves through various endpoints.  WS-Addressing is kind of there with relatesTo, however this is more of relating to an originating message ID.  If we used WS-Addressing and were consistent, then a message chain could be re-constructed across multiple calls.  However, I would prefer to have just a single correlation ID.

In past projects, we have had a single correlation ID, but it went into a custom schema that is in the SOAP header.  Anyway, I wanted to find out if I am missing something in one of the WS-* standards before I define yet another custom schema on my current project.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you're not missing anything. Typically, the JMSCorrelationID is set in the JMS header, not the SOAP header.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this old question. Maybe someone else can benefit of what I found so far.

Have a look at: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xml-dist-app/2001Jul/att-0260/soap-correlation-01.html